# Invalid Size while displaying image

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to retrieve the hidden layer of the VGG16, and display the feature map in Keras. What I am trying to do is to get the `block1_conv1` feature map and get it displayed. But unfortunately, I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Please find the code below:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K


img_path = "bombiliki.jpeg"
img = image.load_img (img_path, target_size=(224,224))
imgArr = image.img_to_array (img)
imgArr = np.expand_dims(imgArr, axis=0)
img = preprocess_input (imgArr)


model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
layer_name = 'block1_conv1'

interMediateOutput = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
features = interMediateOutput.predict (img)
print ("Shape of the feature is ", features.shape)
pic = features[:,:,:,1]
print ("pic shape ", pic.shape)
data = np.asarray(pic)
print ("Data Dimension is ", data.ndim)

plt.imshow (pic)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
('Shape of the feature is ', (1, 224, 224, 64))
('pic shape ', (1, 224, 224))
('Data Dimension is ', 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vgg16.py", line 28, in <module>
    plt.imshow (pic)
  File "/home/navals/anaconda2/envs/musarni/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3205, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/navals/anaconda2/envs/musarni/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/navals/anaconda2/envs/musarni/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5487, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/navals/anaconda2/envs/musarni/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 653, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Comment: is img loaded? can you plot the image?

Comment: No, image is not plotted. I got the error "ypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data"

Comment: @Whoami Where does this error happen? Please include the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `predict` method would return an output of shape `(n_samples, model_output_shape...)`. So if you give it one sample, to get the predictions for the given sample you must do:

```
pic = features[0]
```

And specifically in your example, if you would like to select the output of a specific filter, you need to specify its index as the forth axis:

```
pic = features[0, :, :, desired_filter_index]
```

They you can easily plot that:

```
plt.imshow(pic)
```

Comment: I tried with pic = features[0:,:,:,4], still same error.

Comment: @Whoami The first axis shouldn't be `0:`, it must be `0`.